# Ajax call not working when I modify the html dynamically

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I am building a twitter like app. Attaching a reference of the image here:
[Take a look at how the app looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAFuH.png)

The ajax call is not working instead it takes to the action_url page,when the function **updateHashLinks()** is called after **parseTweets()** inside function **fetchTweets(url)** and **attachTweet(data, true)** inside the ajax call. But if I comment the updateHashLinks() at both places the ajax call is working perfectly. The updateHashLinks() is basically used to add a href tag dynamically to the hashed words like(#Twitter).
The html code which I am using is:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-3 col-xs-12 text-center' style='background-color: gray; height: 30px;'>
        <h6>{{ request.user }}</h6>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-9 text-center'>
        {% if not request.GET.q %}
        <div class="media-body text-left">
            {% include "tweets/form.html" with form=create_form action_url=create_url btn_title='Tweet' form_id='tweet-form' %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div id='tweet-container'>
        </div>
        <a href='#' id=loadmore>Load More Tweets</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Functions Which are Used are:

```
function updateHashLinks() {
    $(".media-body").each(function (data) {
        //data.preventDefault()
        // console.log(this)
        var hashtagRegex = /(^|\s)#([\w\d-]+)/g
        var newText = $(this).html().replace(hashtagRegex, '$1 <a href="/tags/$2/">#$2</a>')
        console.log("-------------------------")
        console.log(newText)
        $(this).html(newText)
    })

}
function attachTweet(value, prepend) {
    console.log("attachtweet")
    var tweetContent = value.content
    // console.log(tweetContent)
    var tweetUser = value.user
    var dateDisplay = value.date_display
    // console.log(tweetUser.url)
    var tweetHtml = "<div class=\"media\"><div class=\"media-body\">" + tweetContent + "<br/> via " + "<a href='" + tweetUser.url + "'>" + tweetUser.username + "</a> | " + dateDisplay + " |" + "<a href='#'>View</a>" + "</div></div><hr/>"
    console.log(tweetHtml)
    // console.log("<div class=\"media-body\">"+tweetContent+"<br/> via "+tweetUser.username+"| "+ dateDisplay +" |"+"<a href='#'>View</a>"+"<hr/>")
    if (prepend == true) {
        $("#tweet-container").prepend(tweetHtml)
    }
    else {
        $("#tweet-container").append(tweetHtml)
    }

}
function parseTweets() {
    if (tweetList == 0) {
        $("#tweet-container").text("No tweets currently found")
    }
    else {
        // console.log("Entering Loop")
        $.each(tweetList, function (key, value) {
            var tweetKey = key
            attachTweet(value)
            // console.log(key)
            // console.log(value.user)
            // console.log(value.content)


        })

    }
}

function fetchTweets(url) {
    console.log("Fetching....")
    var fetchUrl;
    if (!url) {
        fetchUrl = "/api/tweet/"
    }
    else {
        fetchUrl = url
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: fetchUrl,
        data: {
            "q": query
        },
        method: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            tweetList = data.results
            if (data.next) {
                nextTweetUrl = data.next
            }
            else {
                $('#loadmore').css("display", "none")
            }

            parseTweets()
            updateHashLinks()
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("error")
            console.log(data)
        }
    })
}
```

The Ajax call is:

```
$("#tweet-form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var this_ = $(this)
    var formData = this_.serialize()
    console.log(formData)
    console.log(charsCurrent)
    if (charsCurrent >= 0) {
        console.log("Inside the Loop")
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/tweet/create/",
            data: formData,
            method: "POST",
            success: function (data) {

                this_.find("input[type=text],textarea").val("")
                //console.log(data)
                // fetchTweets()
                attachTweet(data, true)
                updateHashLinks()
                // fetchTweets()
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("error")
                console.log(data.statusText)
                console.log(data.status)
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        console.log("The Tweet Length is Too Long")
    }

    // console.log(event)
    // console.log("fetching again...")
    // console.log(this_.serialize())
    // fetchTweets()
})
```

The form code which we submit is here:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<form {% if form_id %} id='{{ form_id }}' {% endif %}class='form' method="POST" action="{% if action_url%}{{ action_url }}{% endif %}"> 
    {% csrf_token %} 
    {{ form|crispy }} 
    <input class = 'btn btn-primary' type="submit" value="{{ btn_title }}"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: you have multiple forms with same IDs?use class instead

Comment: i have only one form in the entire app. It is working correctly if I comment out the UpdateHashLinks() function. The function changes the html and that is where the problem might be I think. Please take a look at that function